# Python - How to output mp4 for 'x' amount of seconds?

Tags: python, mp4

I want to add some code that will allow me to output a mp4. I've tried adding; import moviepy.editor as moviepy, import os with no avail. I'm super new and i'm not sure on the right question to ask. Do I have to use import cv2, or what i think is; pygame.Surface.save() function and save the frames then convernt them in ffmpeg? I want to generate a 30 second to 1 min clip directly converted to a mp4.

```
import pygame
import math
import os
from matrix import matrix_multiplication
from bresenham import bresenham
from numpy import interp

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
background, bright = (13,13,13), (60,180,120)
width, height = 800, 800 

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('ASCII TESSERACT')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

#ASCII FONTS
lineFont = pygame.font.SysFont('scheherazade', 20, bold=False)
cornerFont = pygame.font.SysFont('nachlieliclm', 24, bold=True)

#Tesseract information 
angle = 0 
cube_position = [width//2, height//2]
scale = 2800 
speed = 0.005
points = [n for n in range(16)]

points[0] = [[-1], [-1], [1], [1]]
points[1] = [[1], [-1], [1], [1]]

points\[2\] = \[\[1\], \[1\], \[1\], \[1\]\]
points\[3\] = \[\[-1\], \[1\], \[1\], \[1\]\]
points\[4\] = \[\[-1\], \[-1\], \[-1\], \[1\]\]
points\[5\] = \[\[1\], \[-1\], \[-1\], \[1\]\]
points\[6\] = \[\[1\], \[1\], \[-1\], \[1\]\]
points\[7\] = \[\[-1\], \[1\], \[-1\], \[1\]\]
points\[8\] = \[\[-1\], \[-1\], \[1\], \[-1\]\]
points\[9\] = \[\[1\], \[-1\], \[1\], \[-1\]\]
points\[10\] = \[\[1\], \[1\], \[1\], \[-1\]\]
points\[11\] = \[\[-1\], \[1\], \[1\], \[-1\]\]
points\[12\] = \[\[-1\], \[-1\], \[-1\], \[-1\]\]
points\[13\] = \[\[1\], \[-1\], \[-1\], \[-1\]\]
points\[14\] = \[\[1\], \[1\], \[-1\], \[-1\]\]
points\[15\] = \[\[-1\], \[1\], \[-1\], \[-1\]\]

def connect_point(i, j, k, offset, lineChar = ':', skip = 7):
a = k\[i + offset\]
b = k\[j + offset\]
line = bresenham(a\[0\], a\[1\], b\[0\], b\[1\])

s = skip 
for point in line: 
    s -= 1
    if s == 0:
        # display ASCII character
        text_display(lineChar, point[0], point[1])
    if s < 0:
        s = skip

def text_display(letter, x_pos, y_pos):
text = lineFont.render(str(letter), True, bright)
screen.blit(text, (x_pos, y_pos))

def corner_display(x, y, z, w, interpolateColor = True, fontSizeInterpolate = True):
\# Interpolate z and brightness
if interpolateColor:
interpolatedColor = (interp(z, \[0.1, 0.27\], \[background\[0\], bright\[0\]\]), interp(z, \[0.1,                0.27\], \[background\[1\], bright\[1\]\]), interp(z, \[0.1, 0.27\], \[background\[2\], bright\[2\]\]))
else:
interpolatedColor = bright

# Interpolate w and font size 
if fontSizeInterpolate:
    fontSize = round(int(interp(w, [0.1, 0.27], [50, 76])))
    cornerFont = pygame.font.SysFont('nachlieliclm', fontSize, bold=True)

text = cornerFont.render('.', True, interpolatedColor)
screen.blit(text, (x, y-fontSize / 2))

# Pygame loop

run = True
while run:
clock.tick(fps)
screen.fill(background)
for event in pygame.event.get():
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
run = False
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
run = False

index = 0
projected_points = [j for j in range(len(points))]

# 3D matrix rotations
rotation_x = [[1, 0, 0],
              [0, math.cos(angle), -math.sin(angle)],
              [0, math.sin(angle), math.cos(angle)]]

rotation_y = [[math.cos(angle), 0, -math.sin(angle)],
              [0, 1, 0],
              [math.sin(angle), 0, math.cos(angle)]]

rotation_z = [[math.cos(angle), -math.sin(angle), 0],
              [math.sin(angle), math.cos(angle), 0],
              [0, 0 ,1]]             

tesseract_rotation = [[1, 0, 0],
                      [0, math.cos(-math.pi/2), -math.sin(-math.pi/2)],
                      [0, math.sin(-math.pi/2), math.cos(-math.pi/2)]]

# 4D matrix rotations
rotation4d_xy= [[math.cos(angle), -math.sin(angle), 0, 0],
              [math.sin(angle), math.cos(angle), 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1]]
rotation4d_xz = [[math.cos(angle), 0, -math.sin(angle), 0],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [math.sin(angle), 0, math.cos(angle), 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 1]]
rotation4d_xw = [[math.cos(angle), 0, 0, -math.sin(angle)],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1, 0],
                 [math.sin(angle), 0, 0, math.cos(angle)]]
rotation4d_yz = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, math.cos(angle), -math.sin(angle), 0],
                 [0, math.sin(angle), math.cos(angle), 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 1]]
rotation4d_yw = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, math.cos(angle), 0, -math.sin(angle)],
                 [0, 0, 1, 0],
                 [0, math.sin(angle), 0, math.cos(angle)]]
rotation4d_zw = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, math.cos(angle), -math.sin(angle)],
                 [0, 0, math.sin(angle), math.cos(angle)]]

for point in points: 

    rotated_3d = matrix_multiplication(rotation4d_xy, point)
    rotated_3d = matrix_multiplication(rotation4d_zw, rotated_3d)

    distance = 5
    w = 1/(distance - rotated_3d[3][0])
    projection_matrix4 = [
                        [w, 0, 0, 0],
                        [0, w, 0, 0],
                        [0, 0, w, 0],]

    projected_3d = matrix_multiplication(projection_matrix4, rotated_3d)
    rotated_2d = matrix_multiplication(tesseract_rotation, projected_3d)

    z = 1/(distance - (rotated_2d[2][0] + rotated_3d[3][0]))
    projection_matrix = [[z, 0, 0],
                         [0, z, 0]]

    rotated_2d = matrix_multiplication(rotation_x, projected_3d)
    projected_2d = matrix_multiplication(projection_matrix, rotated_2d)

    x = int(projected_2d[0][0] * scale) + cube_position[0]
    y = int(projected_2d[1][0] * scale) + cube_position[1]

    projected_points[index] = [x, y, z, w]
    corner_display(x, y, z, w)

    index += 1

#draw edges
for m in range(4):
    connect_point(m, (m+1)%4, projected_points, 8)
    connect_point(m+4, (m+1)%4 + 4, projected_points, 8)
    connect_point(m, m+4, projected_points, 8)

for m in range(4):
    connect_point(m, (m+1)%4, projected_points, 0)
    connect_point(m+4, (m+1)%4 + 4, projected_points, 0)
    connect_point(m, m+4, projected_points, 0)

for m in range(8):
    connect_point(m, m+8, projected_points, 0)

angle += speed
pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, you cannot save pygame directly into mp4 and you must use pygame.Surface.save() to save each frame into a .jpg, make it into an array, then make it into an mp4. You can change how often it saves the frame by updating the framecount.

```
import moviepy.editor import *
import moviepy.editor as mp
import os
import glob
import shutil

#Put all your pygame code in here

window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )

while not exiting:
    # handle events
    # paint the screen

    # save the frame
    frame_count += 1
    filename = "screen_%04d.png" % (frame_count)
    pygame.image.save(window, filename) #this saves it in the file
    clock.tick( WINDOW_FPS )
    src_dir = "your/current/dir" #This is where pygame saves the images
    image_dir = "your/destination/dir" #This is where you want the dir to be
    for jpgfile in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src_dir, "*.jpg")):
        shutil.copy(jpgfile, dst_dir)

#Makes the array of images into imgarr
for filename in os.listdir(image_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
        imgarr.append(os.path.join(image_dir, filename))

slides = []
for n, url in enumerate(imgarr): #All Images in imagedir
    slides.append(mp.ImageClip(url).set_fps(1).set_duration(1))
video.mp.concatenate_videoclips(slides)
videoclip.write_videofile("video_1.mp4")
```